# What is the meaning of 'national' as in eg 'Australian national'?

Tags: meaning, terminology, international

From here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/115930/career-prospects-for-a-math-phd-student-in-pure-math

> I am an Australian national and want to live in Australia long term.

what exactly is the meaning of Australian national? like student visa? or actual citizen? or resident?

Answer (score 2):

Australian national = Someone entitled to an Australian passport.

In British and Commonwealth law a national of a given country is the only type of person entitled to a passport of that country.

The right to a passport is governed by the laws of the country. It may be by descent from a national or birth in the country (or one of its territories) or may be granted (or withdrawn) by the government of the country.

(Source 40 years of dealing with questions of nationality.)

Comment: ah thanks Greybeard. so basically it's like citizen? i mean afaik citizens usually have passports (excluding possibly poor people who can't afford to travel. idk), but i think if you're newly a citizen (eg you're newly born or you recently acquired a new citizenship), then you're usually not right away a passport holder

Comment: A national is a person a with a [nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationality).

Comment: @BCLC I may not have been clear: If you hold a country's passport then you are a national of that country. However, if you are *entitled* to hold that country's passport, (whether you have one or not) you a national of that country. Almost everyone on the planet becomes a national of a country at birth. It may be because a parent or grandparent had that nationality and/or because you were born in that country.

Comment: What about people with dual nationality, are they regarded as nationals of both countries, only one country, or are they regarded as not being proper nationals of either country?

Comment: @BoldBen If you have nationalities A and B, when you are in A, you are an A national and may not call on consular assistance from B; when you are in B, you are a B national and may not call on consular assistance from A; when you are in country C, you are an A **and** a B national and may call on either or both - how they respond will depend on several factors.

Comment: @Greybeard Thanks for that, I knew that there were sometimes problems for dual nationals but I wasn't quite sure what they were. It seems it's when they are in third countries, particularly in the case of dual national refugees.

Comment: While this answer **roughly** captures how the word is used in **casual** communication, and while, in these contexts, it it is indeed interchangeable with *citizen*, it needs to be pointed out that in particular legal contexts, *national* may function as a **technical term** with a precisely defined meaning that is different from that of *citizen*. What the difference is, within  a particular legal system, is a legal question, which would be outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @jsw29 so the close vote should be off-topic since legal instead off-topic since lacking research? thanks for commenting!

Comment: Greybeard i think you made a typo. what is 'you a national' in 'If you hold a country's passport then you are a national of that country. However, if you are entitled to hold that country's passport, (whether you have one or not) you a national of that country' ?